# Members of an Array with preceding serial number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a function that takes an array as a parameter and returns a string with the items in the array with a preceding number. For eg. the `line` array below has three members which are `Ava`, `Adam`, `John`. I want the function to return the following string:

`The line is currently: 1. Ava, 2. Adam, 3. John`

```
line = ['Ava', 'Adam', 'John']
function currentLine(line) {
  if (line.length === 0) {
    return "The line is currently empty.";
  }
  return "The line is currently: "
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making this your last return statement:

```
var result = line.map(function (value, index) {
    return (index + 1) + '. ' + value;
}).join(', ');
return "The line is currently: " + result;
```

Comment: Won't that label the items 0, 1, 2 instead of 1, 2, 3?

Comment: [hanging my head in shame emoji]

Comment: This is the best way, in my opinion, because of how concise it is.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var line = ['Ava', 'Adam', 'John']
function currentLine(line) {
    if (line.length === 0) {
        return "The line is currently empty.";
    }
    var newLine = line.map(function (item ,index){
     return (index+1) + ". " + item;
    });
    return "The line is currently: " + newLine.join(", ");
}
console.log(currentLine(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this in the following way ...

```js
let line = ['Ava', 'Adam', 'John'];
function currentLine(line) {
  if (line.length !== 0) {
    let result = "The line is currently: ";
    line.forEach((e, i) => {
      result += (i + 1) + '. ' + e + ', ';
    });
    return result.slice(0,-2);
  } else return "The line is currently empty.";
}
console.log(currentLine(line));
```

Comment: this will produce  an extra " , " at the end. ;)

Comment: So `return result.slice(0,-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Naz-Al,

This code will allow you to achieve the desired results. Plus, you can pass other arrays into the function and achieve the same output.

```js
var line = ['Ava', 'Adam', 'John'];

function currentLine(array) {
 var output = "";
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return "The line is currently empty.";
  }
  else {
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    output += (Number([i]) + 1) + ". " + array[i];
     if(i !== array.length - 1) {
      output = output + ", ";
     }
  }
 }
 return "The line is currently: " + output;
}
```